# Do ninjas attack faster?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

It seems that some of the costumes (such as the ninja outfit) for the monk change the attack animation.  Does this alter the attack speed and/or attack range of the monk at all?

What about the other costumes?

Comment: If you can see the ninja then he's not a real ninja.

Comment: Hard to tell.  You never see them coming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this and many in game players also confirm that the ninja outfit does indeed grant a small bonus to attack speed.

Comment: I actually saw no change in the speed but it -does- change the animation pattern so that the last attack is an AOE swipe instead of the single target thrust.. So while no real attack speed increase, my overall DPS does go up when dealing with multiple targets.

Comment: @James have you tried it with a slow weapon like the ogre party hat?

Answer (score 0):

I will have to do further testing to be 100% sure, but it is fairly clear that the weapons are telling the animations how fast to play for attacking rather than the other way around. This can be seen more clearly on the Squire than the monk where there is a very distinct attack speed difference between the weapons, most clearly the samurai sword and that shield weapon.

This is also clearly seen in the familiars and huntress weapons where attacks per second are an upgrade to the item.. My serpent familiar and huntress twitch quite fast with their 6 attacks per second.

Now that said. I do not have the ninja skin unlocked and its possible that some where in there someone put an

```
if (isNinja)
{
    AttackSpeed = WeaponSpeed * 1.25;
}
```

or something similar... And with all the things that have been changed and 'missing' from their patch notes its possible.. I just consider it doubtful at this time.

Comment: well the attack animation looks completely different as a ninja, so that's why I'm interested in whether or not its faster

Comment: I understand that, but just because it looks different doesnt mean its not told you haev X amount of time before you need to start the next animation based on the weapon speed. Hope to have the skin unlocked in next day or two.. leveling a DPS huntress to go with my tower champs so I should be able to confirm the statements above soon.